# Why doesn't transition: translateX work in this example?

Tags: css

Codepen: https://codepen.io/codepenuserpro/pen/wvyVLLj

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="ease" class="move"><div>Ease (Default)</div></div>
  <div id="linear" class="move"><div>Linear</div></div>
  <div id="ease-in" class="move"><div>Ease In</div></div>
  <div id="ease-out" class="move"><div>Ease Out</div></div>
  <div id="ease-in-out" class="move"><div>Ease In Out</div></div>
</div>


.container
{
  width:90vw;
  border:1px solid red;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.move
{
  margin:2rem;
  width:150px;
  height:50px;
  padding:10px;
  background-color:darkred;
  text-align:center;
  color:white;
  border-radius:0.5rem;
  font-size:20px;
  transition:translateX() 2s;
}

#ease { transition-timing-function:ease; }
#linear { transition-timing-function:linear; }
#ease-in { transition-timing-function:ease-in; }
#ease-out { transition-timing-function:ease-out; }
#ease-in-out { transition-timing-function:ease-in-out; }

.move:hover
{
  transform:translateX(calc(79vw));
}
```

Strange thing is, when you hover over the buttons, the animation looks jumpy and weird.

But when I set the 'transition:translateX() 2s' to 'transition:all 2s' instead, it works!

What causes this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the ❌ `transition:translateX() 2s;` to ✅ `transition: transform 2s;`

bacause `translateX();` is not a css property

> here is a list of valid CSS properties https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Properties_Reference

[image]

Comment: That doesn't look like expected result...it should be animated, not just jump from 0 to 100%

Comment: @vanowmvai corrected

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas Actually, I just realized that you can use translateX(), but it must be with transition-property. I've updated the codepen: https://codepen.io/codepenuserpro/pen/wvyVLLj